# XSLT getting value from XML

Tags: xslt

I have an XML like this

```
<A Rank="1">
  <a1>1</a2>
  <a1>1</a2>
</A1>
<A Rank="2">
  <a1>1</a2>
  <a1>1</a2>
</A1>
```

My XSLT sample is for using that Rank value.

```
<tr>
  <td align="left">
    <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@Rank"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="a1"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to print the rank value. How can I?

Comment: Your XML fragment is not well-formed (even as a fragment).  Have you gotten as far as loading it?

Comment: @user2416473: `select="@Rank"` is just the right thing to do to get the Rank attribute. But this will only work if your current node is the a `A` element. Therefore the problem is not in your fragment, but in the part how you calling this.

Comment: Thnaks that helped a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your correct XSLT should look like:

```
<t>
  <A Rank="1">
    <a1>1</a1>
    <a2>1</a2>
  </A>
  <A Rank="2">
    <a1>1</a1>
    <a2>4</a2>
  </A>
</t>
```

**XSLT1:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="A">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Rank"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(child::*)"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output1:**

```
  <tr><td align="left">#1:2</td></tr>
  <tr><td align="left">#2:5</td></tr>
```

**xslt2:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="A">
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Rank"/>
        <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output2:

```
  <tr><td align="left">#1:1:1</td></tr>
  <tr><td align="left">#2:1:4</td></tr>
```

Comment: Sorry I know it is not well formed. I just want to give an idea and coming to ur answer @Rank is not getting the value back from XML and I dont understand the reason and I want to know what this will do sum(child::*)". Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: sum(child::*)". I understood what this does please help me with @Rank issue it is not giving the value from XML.In fact I am not getting any value.I am just getting #: without any numerical!!!